# Load Thunderbird and have it minimize straight to system tray

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, notification-area

I'm setting up Thunderbird and need the mail program to jump into the system tray right after opening.

I tried a couple plugins that should have made it minimize but they don't see to work (maybe because I am on Windows 7 pro 64bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird does not offer the option 'minimize to tray, but there are plenty ways to skin this cat:

[**TrayIt!**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/TrayIt.shtml) will do the trick.

[image]

or **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)**:

> Automatically maximize or minimize or
>   normal all new windows you specify.
>
> **Automatically minimize all new windows you specify to system tray.**
>
> Automatically keep all new windows you
>   specify always on top.
>
> Adds several menu items to standard
>   window system menu.
>
> Minimize the current window to system
>   tray.
>
> Apply transparency effect from 0%
>   (fully transparent) to 100% (solid)
>   rate to any program in Windows
>   2000/XP/2003/Vista.
>
> Show window property of application,
>   such as window handle, class name,
>   process id etc.
>
> Auto Refresh Internet explorer at
>   custom intervals.

*both programs are free.*

as for Thunderbird to load at startup, create a shortcut and place it in your startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Thunderbird (or any program) to load on startup by following this [tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html).

The extension [MinimizeToTray](http://minimizetotray.mozdev.org/) is said:

> **(In development) -Turbo option for
>   Firefox and Thunderbird.** 
>   MinimizeToTray implements this popular
>   feature from the Mozilla application
>   suite. Have a Firefox tray icon and
>   menu always available, even if no
>   browser window is open.  **Or have
>   Thunderbird launch directly into the
>   tray only to notify you if you receive
>   mail.**

Comment: this extension has not been updated for 3 years and doesn't work with TB2

Comment: It's represented as working for Thunderbird: 1.0+ – 2.0.0.* , with quite a lot of glowing reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck "leave message on server" for that account. Settings -> Server settings. I am german, and I do not know the exact menu texts, but they should sound similar like I posted here.

If that does not work, this may be an issue with gmail. For my varoius accounts (gmx, web.de), this works very fine.